# How to create a square with numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to create a square shape with numbers like this:

```
1234
2341
3412
4123
```

How would I go about doing that?

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <=4; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This prints:

```
1234
234
34
4
```

How do I get it to restart at 1 again?

Comment: See? Million different ways of doing this. :) Just a matter of how you comprehend the problem..

Answer (score 4):

You can do by using modulo

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        System.out.print((j  + i) % 4 + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**output**

```
1234
2341
3412
4123
```

Comment: 8 answers, your's looks just about the best.

Comment: Your code is good. The explanation is... less good, imo. As this q&a stands, it looks a lot like the OP was hoping someone would just do their homework, and they got just that. :-/

Comment: @yshavit Agree with you.  OP got away with it this time, but that type of behaviour doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

    for (int j = i; j <=4; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= 4; j++){
        System.out.print(((i + j + 2) % 4) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If you look at the expected output, it has a pattern, which is restricted to a finite and known sequence of numbers. **Modulus** is the ideal option to handle cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

add one more for loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j <=4; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a simpler way, but this should work:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 3; j <= 6; j++) {
          System.out.print ((i + j) % 4 + 1);
      }
      System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <=4; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
            count += 1;            
        }
        if(count < 4){
            int remain = 4 - count; // to identify how many times it goes again
                for(int k=0;k<remain;k++){
                    System.out.print(k+1);
                }                
            }
            count = 0;
        System.out.println();
    }       
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1234
2341
3412
4123
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(((i + j) % 4) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Modulus (`%`) gives the remainder of one number divided by another, so `(i+j) % 4` always gives a result between 0 and 3.

Add one to that to get the value you want (between 1 and 4).